# Windows 8.1 x64 on a 16GB SSD?

Tags: windows-8, ssd

So I just got a small SSD to use. It's not big, but quite small - 16GB.

However I think it'd speed things up in my old HP 8530W a LOT. But Windows 8 by default is way too big for that.

Is there a chance that it could run from there, say, after a serious trimming of drivers, extra apps and features I do not use, and moving around some folders to my main drive? I'd prefer to have the core OS, the preinstalled apps, and a few small utilities (Total Commander, uTorrent, etc.) on the SSD.

Also, which tool is the recommended one for modifying a Win8.1/Win10 image?

Comment: On paper yes, it requires, yet I've failed so far to install Windows 8 and make it take up more than 10GB. I believe by removing a huge amount of junk I don't need will make it take even less space.

Not to say about Windows 10 - it literally took 4.5GB after install!

Comment: If I recall correctly Windows 8.1 will refuse to install on a 16GB drive, but it does fit. Here's a screenshot of how big my unaltered Windows 8.1 Enterprise Evaluation virtual machine installation is: http://postimg.org/image/uog66y7kx/ . Not even 9GB in size.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the [WIMBOOT Feature of Windows 8.1 Update 1 (KB2919355)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631793.aspx), Windows will work fine with such a small amount of storage. Here Widows runs directly out of the WIM File which [is much smaller compared to extracting all files in the regular way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn594399.aspx).

> Windows image file boot (WIMBoot) lets you set up a PC so that it runs
>   directly from a compressed Windows image file (WIM file).
>
> WIMBoot can significantly reduce the amount of space used by Windows
>   files. This helps you provide more free space to users, and helps you
>   manufacture Windows on PCs with smaller drives.

Comment: It seems to be a great solution, but doesn't it kill the purpose of the SSD? I mean, loading from WIM is a lot slower, so the speed I gain with the SSD, I lose it with the WIM loading, no?

Comment: it works fine with SSDs. They can read data from a large file very fast. WIMBoot doesn't work well on old HDDs (and MS recommends to use it ONLY on flash drives), with the slow access time.

Comment: Hmm, sounds good. But any way I ended up actually buying a 120GB SSD and using the 16GB one in an external USB3.0-SATA3 case for fast storage.

Comment: The limitation about this solution is the CPU speed (for on-the-fly data decompression), not the SSD.