# Can I use CompactOS technology in Windows 7 or 8.1?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8.1, ntfs, compression

Can CompactOS in Windows 10 be used to compress win 7 or win 8.1 available on the same disk (dual boot mode)?

Similarly can I use this to compress other drives also?

Answer (score 2):

No. The CompactOS feature uses the new [4K XPRESS Huffman compression algorithm](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/file-compression-versus-compact-os-in-win-10/b1ba7598-4b26-4475-a0b1-122db7221c00?page=1) instead of the default LZNT1 algorithm in NTFS. That's one of the **new algorithms introduced in Windows 10** so you can't use it in prior Windows versions. That's also why it's possible to [tweak NTFS compression ratio](https://superuser.com/a/1149911/241386) in Windows 10

Anyway **Windows 8.1 already supports [WIMBoot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/w8cookbook/windows-image-file-boot--wimboot-) for reducing system footprint**, although it's *not as efficient* as CompactOS

- [Windows 8.1 x64 on a 16GB SSD?](https://superuser.com/q/829706/241386)
- [Can I install windows 8.1 update 1 on a 30GB ssd](https://superuser.com/q/743506/241386)
- [WIMBoot Explained: How Windows Can Now Fit on a Tiny 16 GB Drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/196416/wimboot-explained-how-windows-can-now-fit-on-a-tiny-16-gb-drive/)

There's no similar thing in Windows 7

> Similarly can I use this to compress other drives also?

No, compactOS is for **compressing selected system files that are read-only**. It won't touch any user files or files that are written to a lot

However **[NTFS already supports compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#File_compression)** since its start, so just use that feature for the other drives. It's what [files with blue names or blue arrows](https://superuser.com/q/1001970/241386) are about. To compress a file or folder right click on it > *Properties > Advanced* and check *Compress contents to save disk space*

[image: Compressed Folders]

You can compress the whole drive by checking the compress option while formatting it, or in the properties window

[image: Compressed drive]

It's also possible to compress from command line with the `compact` command. Run `compact /s /c /f path\to\file\or\folder` or whatever appropriate options

Answer (score 1):

No, the [compactOS feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/hardware/dn940129(v=vs.85).aspx) is Windows 10 only and not available to older versions. Try to [cleanup WinSxS](https://superuser.com/a/594216/174557) to reduce the size of Windows 7/8.